# Does Laravel-Excel has native method of PHP Excel?

Tags: phpexcel, laravel-excel

I want to use Laravel-Excel, but my concern is which can I use native PHP-Excel method or not, as I have read the documentation. Laravel-Excel is run on of PHP-Excel.

Comment: If you want to use Laravel-Excel, use Laravel-Excel. If you want to use PHPExcel directly, use PHPExcel directly. What is the problem?

Comment: I have used PHPExcel now I want to use Laravel-Excel thus I asked, that dose Laravel-Excel have ability or native method or no ?

Answer (score 1):

From [Laravel-Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) github page:

> An eloquent way of importing and exporting Excel and CSV files for Laravel with the power of PHPExcel

So yes, this package is just a wrapper around the PHPExcel package but it adds conveniences for a laravel project as it follows `Laravel`'s own `Eloquent` model.